# How can I run a report with Pending (Incomplete Transaction)?

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

Essentially I want the contribution detail report but to filter Contribution Status: Pending, Is Pay Later: No

(I know I can do this with search)

I can do this with some extensions, but they do not hyperlink to the contact or contribution for easy access.

D7 Civi 5.32

Answer (score 2):

Pay Later isn't available in reports provided by core civicrm. I added this to extendedreport extension recently - https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/pull/434

The PR is merged so you can use the latest (or master) version and use contribution details extended report to find the required filter.